# Define version of jQuery Mobile by its code

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-mobile, cdn, google-cdn

How to find the version number of the 
[latest version of jQuery Mobile Date: Wed Feb 13 23:27:57 2013 -0500](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js) ?

That's not the file I can find anywhere else, tried to google it.

I need a fixed CDN url path to this file, so it goes exactly to this version in the nearest future, not the most current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

Actually the version can be found in the file, open the file and search for version. In your question you'll find that it the jQuery lib is of version:"1.3.0-rc.1"

**Old answer**

Have you tried the http://jquerymobile.com/download/ page ?
You can specify the version, instead of using the "latest" version like:

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

Comment: Thank you, but I need exactly that file. The other (the previous) don't work for 100% for the project or I have to test/fix it. It could take hours or even more.

Comment: That's one of the problems using "latest". The 1.3.0RC1 does not do the trick for you? http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js?

Comment: I'm not sure, I would have to test it, but I would definitely prefer the fixed url to this file. But why don't they put the version number in the file, it take only 10 bytes so I wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: actually the do specify the version. Open the file and search for version:  ... and the version of the build will show up.

Comment: Thank you, that was the best answer (1 of 1 :) ), although
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js
and
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js
look different not just by parameters, but by the date as well. But, thank you.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please mark it as correct. I guess that you can rely on the version in the file, the dates just indicates when the build of the file was made and parameter-names are made unreadable by a minifier

Comment: I'm still not sure these two compressed files have the same original source (carefully looked up both files). Please let me wait for another opinion.

Comment: @Haradzieniec true, comparing http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js and http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.js in winmerge reveals small differences

Comment: Thank you for your opinion and confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Open the jQuery file, i.e. jquery.mobile.min.js or jquery.mobile.js. Top of the file, in comments, it'll tell you its version number like this:

```
/*! jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 | Git HEAD hash: 9d9a42a <> 2014-02-28T17:32:01Z | (c) 2010, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
```